# Can i have help understanding what the syntax error is in my python SQL query?

Tags: python, sql

I'm new to programming and am trying to understand how i can draw a line of information from SQL lite where the unique factor happens to be the username?

```
import sqlite3

conn=sqlite3.connect("customer database.db")

#line 7 and 9 needed to connect sql database in between
#will show the lines of information they want retrieve
cursor=conn.cursor()
#is just necessary step
userlogin=input("please login")


#line of logic does not compute to python but works directly in SQL
sqlgetcus = f"SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE username is "{userlogin}""


cursor.execute(sqlgetcus)

row=cursor.fetchone()
assert row[0]== userlogin


print(row)
```

Comment: Can you add your error message with the full backtrace in your question?

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Can't really test the rest but I think this is the problem :
You wrote :

```
f"SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE username is "{userlogin}""
```

but what you really wanted to do is :

```
f"SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE username is {userlogin}"
## OR
"SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE username is {}".format(userlogin)
```